# How to use custom highlight in Jupyterlab extension?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am building a server extension for **Jupiter Lab**. I am using cookie-cutter template as an entry point for my extension.

I want to **override the default highlighting for .ipynb files** and **highlight only some custom words**.

How can I achieve this?

**I am using typescript & python for developing my extension.**

Comment: what is the default highlighting?

Comment: @krassowski By default highlighting, I meant the one that comes with jupyter lab for ipynb files. For example, 
for "import numpy as np",
import - Deep green,
numpy - black,
as - Deep green,
np - black

Comment: ah syntax highlighting. Do you want to change colours only or which words are highlighted too? Do you want to change this for Python or add highlighting for another language?